# what changes need to do for working symfony_demo project?

Tags: symfony

I downloaded symfony_demo project but not able to run properly.

I have symfony3 ,get the following error if i update schema :

[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
  An exception occured in driver: could not find driver

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  could not find driver

[PDOException]
  could not find driver

doctrine:schema:update

I would like to mention that i installed sqlite3 and the tables are also shown there.

This is my default parameters.yml file :

```
parameters:
    database_driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    database_url: 'sqlite:///%kernel.root_dir%/data/blog.sqlite'        
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: 
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: secret_value_for_symfony_demo_application
```

So please help me. I have been trying to resolve it for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

With sqlite3 your parameter database_driver should be :

'pdo_sqlite'